# Silex don't register the session after login

Tags: php, silex

My Silex App is working fine, but I'm having a problem at the moment of create the SESSION with the USER.

It makes the auth well, because if user credentials are correct, then redirect to the main prompt as expected, and if credentials are wrong, still in the form.
But if I try to get the user information, it's empty.

```
if (null !== $token) {
    $user = $token->getUser();
}
```

Well, the code I'm using in the app.php is the next:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'remember_me'   => array(),
            'pattern' => '^/login/',
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login/login_check'),
            'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/login/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
            'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
                return new Project\Controller\UserProvider($app['db']);
            }),
        ),
    )
));
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved this way.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
'security.firewalls' => array(
    'login' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/login$',
    ),
    'secured' => array(
        'remember_me'   => array(),
        'pattern' => '^.*$',
        'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login/login_check'),
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/login/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
        'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
            return new Eumed\Controller\UserProvider($app['db']);
        }),
    ),
    'unsecured' => array(
        'anonymous' => true,
    )
),
'security.access_rules' => array(
    array('^/.+$', 'ROLE_USER'),
    array('^/login$', 'SS'),
)
));
```

Comment: I know this is old but can you explain how this create a session for your user after he login your site please?